# Creating new rows in a table without exiting a tr

Tags: html, css, django-forms

I have written this code for my perfect layout. Unfortunately I have a complicated js library based on [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/formsets/). Which requires me to use table rows.

```css
   table {
     width: 100%
   }

   th {
     text-align: left;
     font-size: 30px;
   }
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>D</th>
      <th>E</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan='3'>Lorem ipsum Dorem</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

So I need an alternative way using styling to appear like the above with only one `<tr>` tag i.e:

```
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td class='break'>Lorem ipsum Dorem</td>
  <td class='break'>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Have you tried embedding a table?

Comment: @DriveItLikeYouStoleIt yes! My complicated ha won’t pick it up!

Comment: Then I guess I'd just try divs :/